# How do I generate a string like a Api key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, api-key

I am making an API & seeking help to find a way to generate a random string that will work as an API key.

Let's say you are making an account with News API. You signed up and you would get an API key. How would you generate that same key, but randomly?

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid

Comment: I use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`UUID package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) or [`generate-api-key package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-api-key) to generate a random string.